# How to cast SQL query date to Angular integer more efficient

Tags: php, sql, angularjs

I am using this function for polling but I have a unnecessary step and I want to by-pass it in a more practical way. However I have no idea how to do it:

```
if(!$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mtp ORDER BY date DESC")){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
} else {
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $records[] = $rows;
    } //UNNECCESSARY STEP
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($records); $i++) {
        $records[$i][date] = strtotime($records[$i][date]) * 1000;
    }  //UNNECCESSARY STEP
}
print( json_encode($records));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the loops into one.

```
if(!$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mtp ORDER BY date DESC")){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
} 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $row["date"] = strtotime($row["date"]) * 1000;
    $records[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($records);
```

I don't know why you multiply the time integer with a thousand though?
And if your if sentence contains exit() or die() you don't need an else.

Comment: Thanks for both the warnings and the answer. I don't know why but somehow Angular date object needs `TIMESTAMP()` to be multiplied with 1000.